# How to swap Row Values in pl/sql - Oracle ?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following cursor in PL/SQL:

```
ID     Team     OrigRank     RegSesRank
7844   XXX      2            8
7854   YYY      1            1
```

I need to be able to write some kind of an if-else statement to swap  the `origRank` Values **IF** its `RegSesRank` is greater than the other `RegSesRank`

i.e. the above will not change because `7844` has a greater `RegSesRank` than `7854` therefore `OrigrRank` should not change, however, `OrigRank` must be swaped in case `7854` had a greater `RegSesRank`.

I hope I was clear. Please let me know if you have any questions, and I really really appreciate your help

Comment: Please be aware storing row-relative data in a column violates Relational database normalization. The way you're supposed to do this is with aggregate functions, but since you have not told us what `OrigRank` and `RegSesRank` mean I have no idea what to replace them with.

Comment: What are OgiRank and RegsesRank? Without knowing what purpose they serve it may not be possible to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't solve this problem with an if/else statement in a PL/SQL cursor, because it refers to other rows of the query. Instead, I'd use an `UPDATE` to change all the origRank to the new value if necessary.

The usual way is a nested `UPDATE (SELECT ... FROM mytable JOIN ... ) SET origrank = newrank WHERE origrank != newrank`. To give an example, we'd need to know how the new rank is computed as @Joe W and @Dour High Arch pointed out.